How to get call back for changes in content in Liferay CMS
I have stored the contents/ pdf and text files in CMS. of Liferay.
Now want to be notified when new contents is added/ deleted/ updated in a folder hierarchy/ in sub folders in a page.
How to programmatically do it in Java

It's important to know what version you're using. In the last versions, Java customizations are less recommended, because the tend to be troublesome when upgrading. But they still work well.
If you really want to do it in Java, I recommend that you implement a ModelListener and deploy it to Liferay.
https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360018170891-Model-Listener
Hope this helps
